# Compare two different arrays with same objects structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

There is only one problem - compare arrays with objects.
This is initial array

```
[
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '1',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '2',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '4',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '10',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": false
    }
]
```

This is new array with items

```
[
    {
        "id": '1',
        "path": "some text"
    },
    {
        "id": '4',
        "path": "some text"
    }
    ,
    {
        "id": '6',
        "path": "some text"
    }
]
```

As you can see, "item" in initial array has the same structure as objects in new array, but MIGHT have different ID.

I need to

- keep only items with id 1 and 4 with current "active";
- remove id: 2
- and add id: 6

So result here must be

```
[
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '1',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '4',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "id": '6',
            "path": "some text"
        }
        "active": false
    },
]
```

"active" false by defaut, so for 6 or any new item it must be false.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried combine two filters, but was able to find only objects that are new. Here it's only id 6. How to remove 2 and 10? And how get the final result?

Comment: Please how *how* you tried to combine two filters.

Comment: I'm filtering new array and inside I'm filtering old array. So i'm comparing each new object to each old object.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: 1) My ettempt are not succesful. No need to see it. 2) "how to ask", always the same. I show initial data, new data, and result. What else can be provided?! 3) And as always there are people who giving great answers with perfecr result without qustioning.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. We will help with specific questions, but without seeing your attempt, your algorithm, we can't do much. You might be very close and only need little tweaks. Part of "How to Ask" is "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Please edit your question to address the problems instead of simply [asserting that the problems don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77361577/3).

Comment: @mykaf this is not coding service? Are you sure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript?rq=1  OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically?rq=1

Comment: @mykaf so? What is the diff between questions above and mine?

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all id and map new objects.

```js
const
    oldItems = [{ item: { id: '1', path: "some text" }, active: true }, { item: { id: '2', path: "some text" }, active: true }, { item: { id: '4', path: "some text" }, active: false }, { item: { id: '10', path: "some text" }, active: false }],
    newItems = [{ id: '1', path: "some text" }, { id: '4', path: "some text" }, { id: '6', path: "some text" }],
    ids = new Set(...oldItems.map(({ item: { id } }) => id)),
    result = newItems.map(item => ({ item, active: ids.has(item.id) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: My bad, may I ask to change it to ts?

Comment: sorry, i do not know *ts*.

Comment: Ok, but another my mistake - id is a number. If I change in your code id to numbers there is error.

Comment: above are only strings ...

Comment: Yes, but id must be number. I put string there, and this is wrong.

Comment: Still need help with id as number.